# Declare a List of Map in a class with Dart and Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried delcaring a `List<Map<String, Object>> _work;` with different syntax but it still failed and gave an error

```
type 'MappedListIterable' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>> .....
MappedListIterable is from dart:_internal
List is from dart:core
Mapis is from dart:core
String is from dart:core
Object is from dart:core
.....
```

I want to declare a variable which is a list of Map with key being String and value being Object. How should I do it?

Many thanks for any helps

Comment: Please show us a code snippet where that error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `.toList()` missing to make the `MappedListIterable` a proper list. If you call `.map()`, `.where()`, or similar functions on a `List`, you get a `MappedListIterable`, and only calling `.toList()` (or other ways that iterate the `MappedListIterable`) materialize the result, because such operations are lazy and delayed until the result is actually accessed.

Alternatively you might be able to change

```
List<Map<String, Object>> _work;
```

to

```
Iterable<Map<String, Object>> _work;
```

Answer (score 0):

With **Dart 2.x** you can also try to cast `MappedListIterable` to `List` and return `toList()` solving your issue in a simple one-line command:

```
(dictionary['key'] as List).map((item)=> {}).toList();
```